# Orthonormal basis of operators from orthonormal basis in l^2

Tags: calculus, number-theory, trigonometry, orthogonality, trigonometric-integrals

Is there a simple formula for:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s,j,k,l=0}^N\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{cos(st)sin(jt)cos(kt)sin(lt)}{2jl} dt,
\end{equation}
where $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

---

**Number Theory-esque Conclusion:**

Unless I made a typo I reduced it to:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{s,j,k,l=0}^N\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{
\left( sin((i+j) t) + sin((i-j) t)\right)*
\left( sin((k+l) t) + sin((k-l) t)\right)
}{4jk} dt \\
& = \frac{\sum_{s,j,k,l=0}^N
\delta_{i+j = k+l} +\delta_{i+j = k-l} +\delta_{i-j = k+l} + \delta_{i-j = k-l}
}{4jk} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{s,j,k,l=0}^N
\delta_{i+j = k-l}
}{2jk}
+
\frac{\sum_{s,j,k,l=0}^N
\delta_{i+j = k+l} + \delta_{i-j = k-l}
}{4jk}
\end{align},
but even this seems very difficult as it reduces to a counting argument which I'm uncertain of how to approach.

Comment: ??? None of those integrals exist.

Comment: Methinks he might want to integrate on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Maybe he is taking a measure like $\nu$ where for example $\frac{d\nu}{d m} = e^{-t}$, and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Moreover, if indices begin at 0, a lot of denominators are 0...

Comment: Ok assume it begins at 1